# Is it possible to show an object from form A in form B (VB.NET)?

Tags: vb.net

What is the best solution to display an object shown in FORM A, in FORM B? 
I'm using Visual Studio 2019, writing code in VB.NET.

Lets say that:

1) I have a ListView1, shown in FORM A. 
2) I'll need to use the same
    object in FORM B.

I don't want to create a brand new ListView to refer the values, but in fact display the ListView1 programmatically in FORM B.

If this is not a best practice, I accept other suggestions.

What I've tried so far:

Form A code:

```
//Public declaration of ListView1 as an object
Public SpoolOfProcesses As Object = ListView1
```

Form B code:

```
//on Load event
FormA.SpoolOfProcesses.Show
```

I have just performed some web researches but didn't found anything similar. Thank you fellows.

Comment: WPF or WInForms?

Comment: Im using WinForms. What is WPF ?

Comment: You cannot put the same display control on two different forms. On the second form you will need to create a new one and populate it the same way as you did the first

Comment: This is misguided. You should be passing only data between forms and then each form should display that data however is appropriate. That you don;t want to create another control is irrelevant. Likely, you shouldn't be using a `ListView` anyway. Many people use a `ListView` when they should be using a `DataGridView`. The latter supports data-binding where the former does not, so populating it with data is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

In WinForms I would probably pass the `.Items` ListViewItemCollection to FormB, and then AddRange them to the `.Items` of FormB's listview.

FormB's constructor:

```
Public Sub New(x as ListView.ListViewItemCollection)
  listViewOnFormB.Items.AddRange(x)
End Sub
```

FormA's code that shows formB:

```
...
Dim george as New FormB(listViewOnFormA.Items)
george.Show()
...
```